# EC2 Image Builder is not working in Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-private-link

I'm trying to set up a pipeline for EC2 Image Builder in a private subnet using PrivateLink,but I'm getting the following error:

```
Workflow Execution ID: 'wf-d3d5bfb1-e3f7-40d1-b439-8268b822fd18' failed with reason: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances [[i-0e981c5038ba1a290]] not in a valid state for account 208157287953 in workflow step LaunchBuildInstance
```

Knowing that I have done the following:

1. Used an administrator access policy for the EC2 image instance role (for troubleshooting propose).
2. I entirely opened up the Inbound and Outbond Security group traffic (for troubleshooting propose)
3. I setted up a PrivateLink connection for the following services: EC2ImageBuilder, SSM, and S3.

Unfortunately I still not able to run the pipeline successfully.

Anyone who experienced a similar issue or succeeded to run EC2 Image Builder in a private subnet?